# Problem with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have javascript enabled in firefox..But it doesnt appear to work:

```
<head runat="server">

<title></title>
<script src="Jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { alert('Ready to do your bidding!'); });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('Welcome to StarTrackr! Now no longer under police …');


    });

</script>
```

No Alert appears

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script src="Jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { alert('Ready to do your bidding!'); });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're combining an external script with inline script. You need two script tags.

```
<script src="Jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () { alert('Ready to do your bidding!'); });

  $(document).ready(function () {
      alert('Welcome to StarTrackr! Now no longer under police …');


  });

</script>
```

Comment: All script tags should have the type in them.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Many many people use the HTML5 Doctype, including Google. Keep up.

Comment: Good to know.  I didn't know you could set the HTML5 doctype even though the browser (like IE8) supports hardly any of HTML5.  What does Google do when presented with IE6 or IE7?

Comment: @jfriend00 Pretty sure they dropped IE6 years ago. Along with non-js support.

Comment: @jfriend00: IE6 is obslete. do you know that Microsoft stopped supporting XP which the last OS to have IE6? another thing is that `type='text/javascript'` is also obslete. the new type is `type="application/javascript"`. Read this if you have got time http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt

Comment: Did Google really drop IE6 for http://www.google.com or for adserving?  And, what about IE7?  Dropping IE6 for Google Apps makes sense.

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure they dropped IE6 completely.

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate your link to jquery and your javascript...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { alert('Ready to do your bidding!'); });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('Welcome to StarTrackr! Now no longer under police …');


    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this instead:

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="Jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () { alert('Ready to do your bidding!'); });
$(document).ready(function () {
alert('Welcome to StarTrackr! Now no longer under police …');
});
</script>
```

Also, make sure that your "Jquery.js" link isn't broken either. Try visiting it in your web browser and if it doesn't work that might be the problem.

Answer (score -2):

You should try

```
window.alert('Ready to do your bidding!');
```

and

```
window.alert('Welcome to StarTrackr! Now no longer under police …');
```

Comment: That's probably not going to work either as the op has wrapped the code within a script block that is looking at an outside location for the script and the script block inside won't be run.